# CSS boarders on floating divs

Tags: css, border

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/YCJ8Y/1/)I have a set 8 floated divs, each taking 25% width (and having another div and img inside), so they line up in two rows.

```
<div class="galleryboard" id="gallery3">
<div class="view view-first">
  <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/1.jpg">  
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/1.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/2.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/2.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/3.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/3.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/4.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/4.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/5.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/5.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/6.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/6.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/7.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/7.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-first">
    <img src="img/galleries/3/thumb/8.jpg">
    <div class="mask">
        <a href="img/galleries/3/full/8.jpg"  class="info group1">Enlarge</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to add only the inner borders to all floats by manually picking each float by css, like so:

```
 .view:nth-child(1) {
border-left:none
 }
 .view:nth-child(5) {
border-left:none
 }
 .view:nth-child(4) {
border-right:none
 }
 .view:nth-child(8) {
border-right:none
 }
 .view:nth-child(1), .view:nth-child(2), .view:nth-child(3), .view:nth-child(4) {
border-top:none;
 }
 .view:nth-child(5), .view:nth-child(6), .view:nth-child(7), .view:nth-child(8) {
border-bottom:none;
 }
```

but somehow, I'm getting the borders of 2nd, 3rd, 6th and 7th float all wrong - see it here

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCJ8Y/1/)

the divs are styled here

```
 .view {
width: 25%;
box-sizing:border-box;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
 border:3px solid blue
 }
 .view .mask, .view .content {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.view img {
display: block;
position: relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

and apparently the problem is caused by the img having its width set to 100%. Can you find a solution to have my inner borders all the same size? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
Remove all child styling and apply following

```
.view:nth-child(1), .view:nth-child(2), .view:nth-child(3), .view:nth-child(5), .view:nth-child(6), .view:nth-child(7) {
   border-right: medium none;
}

.view:nth-child(1), .view:nth-child(2), .view:nth-child(3), .view:nth-child(4) {
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
```

In the .view i have just added height or pass the height dynamicaly

```
.view {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    **height: 240px;**
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I set the height for both .view and .view img with JS and everything works to my taste....